# Why does Java have much better performance vs other interpreted languages?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, interpreter

Why does Java have much better performance compared to other interpreted languages like Python? I know this probably has something to do with the fact that it's compiled beforehand, but what about concurrency?

How is the JVM able to perform so much better with concurrent programs, whereas interpreted languages have to do deal with things like global interpreter locking etc, that really slow things down?

Comment: On modern full featured platforms the runtime compiles it into native code.  The interpreter is only used initially to gather statistics to make optimizations on the native code generated.

Comment: Java is not fully interpreted like Python either, but instead is compiled to an intermediary language called the Java Bytecode, which is much faster to interpret.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers so far. I was a bit nervous about posting  my first question.

Comment: @BaileyS Python is compiled to bytecode, too.

Comment: @sepp2k, I did not know that about Python, but the point does still apply to comparisons with PHP, Perl, etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a really interesting question, but I'm not sure there's a simple way to answer it.  JVMs these days use a range of highly aggressive optimizations to try to improve performance.  Here are a few:

- **Dynamic compilation:** Most good JVMs can dynamically compile the bytecode directly into machine code, which then executes at native speeds.
- **Polymorphic inline caching:** Many JVMs use [inline caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching) to try to improve the performance of method dispatching by remembering which functions have been called in the past.
- **Static typing:** Since Java is statically-typed, bytecode instructions rarely have to do expensive introspection on the type of an object to determine how to perform an operation on it.  Field offsets can be computed statically, and method indices in a virtual function table can be precomputed as well.  Contrast this with languages like JavaScript, which don't have static typing and are much harder to interpret.
- **Garbage collection:** The JVM garbage collector is optimized to allocate and deallocate objects efficiently.  It uses a combination of mark-and-sweep and stop-and-copy techniques to make most allocations really fast and to make it easy to reclaim lots of memory quickly.
- **Known choke points:** Rather than having a huge VM lock, some JVM implementations automatically insert extra code into each piece of compiled/interpreted code to periodically check in with the VM and determine whether they can keep running.  That way, if the JVM needs to do garbage collection in only a few threads, it can do so while the other threads are running.  If it needs to do a stop-the-world operation, it will only occur when the threads hit specific points, meaning that simple operations don't have to continuously check in with the VM state.

There are many, many more optimizations in place that I'm probably not aware of, but I hope that this helps you get toward an answer!

Comment: It is also worth noting that Java is not interpreted directly, but instead pre-compiled to psuedo-asm instructions which are much quicker to handle at run time than the full text of a programming language.

Comment: There is the JIT, too, which is a huge factor

Comment: @fge- That's a good point.  I listed this as "dynamic compilation" rather than JIT.

Comment: HMmyes, but most of the JIT work is to transform bytecode sequences into other bytecode sequences... If I'm not mistaken, compilation to machine code is quite new, isn't it?

Comment: @fge: Only if you consider "1999" or "Java 1.2" quite new -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot

Answer (score 3):

Java code has next to no optimisation during compilation.

The runtime JIT does most of the compilation.

What may be different about Java is that it relatively feature poor with minimal side effects.   This makes the code easier to optimise.

> whereas interpreted languages have to do deal with things like global interpreter locking etc, that really slow things down?

This is an implementation issue.  Java was designed with multi-threading support from the start.  I suspect python was designed for scripting and rapid development cycles, something it does much better as a result.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the last point.