# Why are nested Java loops done incredibly fast

Tags: java, optimization, nested-loops

Out of curiosity, I recently wrote two nested for loops in Java and both of them simply counted to 1 billion (1'000'000'000).

Surprisingly, Java had this task done in less than one second. In other languages this would never be done that quickly.

Another weird thing is that when I add a third for loop, nested as well, the program did not seem to come to an end.

Can someone tell me where that speed comes from?

**Edit:**

Following is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { 
    for (int r = 0; r < 1000000000; r++) { } 
} 
System.out.println("done");
```

Answer (score 3):

The java compiler optimizes the loop and removes it. But this isn't the case if you use a volatile int:

```
static volatile int i;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++);
}
```

The above loop will take a lot of time because now the java compiler can't optimize the loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Assuming Your using Java 8 a great deal of performance optimizations have been made to java over the years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032383/why-does-java-have-much-better-performance-vs-other-interpreted-languages). [As this test shows for & while loops are way faster than iterators](http://www.mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/). Just going through a loop is one of the fastest operations you can perform. As mentioned by @kevin in the comments the compiler is most likely deciding to skip iterations of the loop to optimize the code. This is why the poor mans sleep functions (count to a large number, were never really that accurate ([the second answer mentions about how compilers optimize this hence making these primitive do it yourself sleep functions unreliable.])[3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/using-a-for-loop-instead-of-sleeping)

The reason why the third loop fails is because your exponentially increasing the size. Your effectively trying the to iterate to 1 billion then 1billion to the second power then 1 billion to the third power.

Also what languages are you comparing these results to and are you sure your code is similar. Also for your third case you may just need to wait for it to finish executing assuming you dont get an Error/Exception.

Comment: Also the compiler could just decide to optimize and/or skip loops or iterations if they don't have any effect.

Comment: true where it might be interesting to run your code with java 4 or java 5 and see if those optimizations are still there. I know improving the performance was a really big theme for java 6 and 7.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. I also thought the second loop is just omitted but then I printed second loop's variable and it was 1 billion. So it apparently omits the loop but sets the variable nevertheless to 1 billion. I tried the same in C and Assembly but they did'nt get results as fast as with java

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The compiler is optimizing the code by removing your loops entirely, since they have no effect whatsoever on the program.

Try it this way and see what happens:

```
int i, r;
for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { 
    for (r = 0; r < 1000000000; r++) { } 
}

System.out.println(String.format("Done. i=%d r=%d", i, r));
```

Now I'm forcing the compiler to compile the loops since `i` and `r` are accessed from both inside and outside the loops.

Comment: That was also my anticipation. The code looks like this.                                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
      {
       for (int r = 0; r < 1000000000; r++)
       {
        
       }
      }
      System.out.println("done");

Comment: @johnw This is definitely a compiler optimization. I edited my answer accordingly.